# How to write query to retrieve all table1.* where all related table2.value = x?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assuming we have this test tables and values :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys 
           WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'FK_table2_table1') 
             AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.table2') )
    ALTER TABLE dbo.table2 
        DROP CONSTRAINT FK_table2_table1
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
           WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.table2') AND type IN (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE dbo.table2
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
           WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.table1') AND type IN (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE dbo.table1
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.table1
(
    id int NOT NULL,
    name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_table1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id ASC)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.table2
(
    id int NOT NULL,
    table1_id int NOT NULL,
    type tinyint NOT NULL,
    bool bit NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_table2 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id ASC)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.table2 WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_table2_table1 
        FOREIGN KEY (table1_id) REFERENCES dbo.table1 (id)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.table1 VALUES (1, 'a')
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 VALUES (2, 'b')
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 VALUES (3, 'c')
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 VALUES (4, 'd')
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.table2 VALUES (1, 1, 2, 0)
INSERT INTO dbo.table2 VALUES (2, 1, 2, 1)

INSERT INTO dbo.table2 VALUES (3, 2, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO dbo.table2 VALUES (4, 2, 1, 1)

INSERT INTO dbo.table2 VALUES (5, 3, 2, 0)
INSERT INTO dbo.table2 VALUES (6, 3, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO dbo.table2 VALUES (7, 3, 1, 1)

INSERT INTO dbo.table2 VALUES (8, 4, 0, 0)
GO
```

How to retrieve all table1.id where ONLY table2.type =  ?
=> must return 1 , 2 , 4

How to retrieve all table1.id where table2.type contains MIXED value (0, 1 or 2)
=> must return 3

Have tried without success using `GROUP BY / HAVING` clause.

Comment: table2.type  equal to what? your logic is not clear

Comment: As of SQL Server **2016**, you should use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  ......` instead of those ugly `IF EXISTS()` checks....

Answer (score 1):

for your first query the logic is not clear , but I assume this is what you want :

```
select table1_id from table2
group by table1_id
having count(distinct type)= 1
```

for second one :

```
select table1_id from table2
group by table1_id
having count(distinct type)> 1
```

Comment: Yes, it is what I want.
Doesn't know that I can use DISTINCT also in the having clause

In the mean time also found something :

`select table1_id
 from table2
 group by table1_id
 having min(type) = max(type)`

Your query is much simple to understand

Thanks a lot